# Is there a way to make the message box show up in front of a PyGame Window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, ctypes

For school, we have to code this dumb zombies game but whatever, onto the question.

I'm using the module 'ctypes' to get a message box in python but whenever we use it, the message box is showing up below the PyGame Window, which is really annoying, because we have to click on the tab at the bottom and it's just a glorified pain. Here's the code:

```
answer = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Save survivor using ammo?", "Oh no, a zombie is approaching!", 4)
if answer == 6:
    survivor()
    ammo -= 1
```

It's a prompt that asks to save the survivor or abandon them, but the message box keeps showing up at the bottom. Is there some kind of parameter that I can apply that puts it in front of the pygame window?

Comment: Please add a the *PyGame* window (or a dummy one) code as well.

Comment: I made a window and called the API as shown and the box was on top of the window.  Provide enough code to reproduce the problem.  You might try calling `GetActiveWindow()` and passing it as the first parameter to `MessageBoxW`.  The message box should appear in front of the owning window.  You've pass 0 (null) meaning no owner.

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

[`MessageBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox) supports the `uType` flag `MB_TOPMOST` (`0x00040000`):

```py
MB_YESNO = 4
MB_TOPMOST = 0x40000
uType = MB_YESNO | MB_TOPMOST
answer = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(
    0, "Save survivor using ammo?", "Oh no, a zombie is approaching!", uType)
```